# Error in barrier option pricing Monte Carlo

Tags: option-pricing, monte-carlo, python, error

I am currently trying to price an up-and-out call with Monte Carlo simulation. For an option with these parameters :

- Barrier: 65
- $K$ = 50
- $\sigma$ = 30%
- $R $ = 1%
- $T$ = 1Y
- $S_0$ = 50

With 10.000 simulations and $dt = \frac{1}{500}$ I obtain an option price close to 0.80 (95% interval confidence : [0.76 ; 0.853]) whereas a pricer gives 0.73.
When rising number of simulations the price increases so I am likely doing something wrong.

Here is the python chunk of code that I use:

```
all_final_payoffs = np.zeros((nb_simulations,1),dtype=float)

for i in tqdm(range(nb_simulations)):
    path_generated_asset = np.zeros((1, nb_time), dtype=float)
    path_generated_asset[0, 0] = S0
    for j in range(1, nb_time):
        X = np.random.randn(1)
        path_generated_asset[0, j] = simulate_price(path_generated_asset[0, j - 1], interest_rate, volatility, dt, X)
    all_final_payoffs[i,0] = compute_barrier_call_payoff(path_generated_asset[0,:],strike,barrier)
option_price = np.mean(all_final_payoffs)*math.exp(-interest_rate*maturity)
```

And the two functions used :

```
def compute_barrier_call_payoff(asset_path,strike,barrier):
    if max(asset_path)>=barrier:
        return 0
    else:
        if asset_path[-1]-strike>0:
            return asset_path[-1]-strike
        return 0

def simulate_price(S,R,Vol,dt,X):
    return S*math.exp((R-(Vol**2)/2)*dt + Vol*math.sqrt(dt)*X)
```

Does someone know where my error is? Thanks a lot!

***Edit***: When increasing the number of simulations to 20.000 and time steps to 2000, I get the price in 3 minutes (very long) on Python.
Same code in C# on the same Mac, the program gives me the result in 7 seconds. When increasing simulations to 50.000 and time steps to 4.000 it takes roughly 35 seconds to give me 0.74$.

***Edit 2*** : Launching the Python code with Cython and typed variables it takes 1 minute.

Comment: What happens if you take $dt$ smaller?

Comment: With $ dt = \frac{1}{1000}$ and I obtained 0.778 (1 minute), with $dt = \frac{1}{2000}$ I got 0.71 (1 min 45 sec) and finally with 20.000 simulations and $dt = \frac{1}{2000}$ I got 0.76 (3 min 50).
It seems better when decreasing $ dt$, thanks a lot!

Comment: One of the ways in which a barrier option is tackled, is to measure how close you are to the barrier while still in. If you get closer, you make your time measurements finer so as to not miss a possible crossing. If you are far away, you can keep larger time steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path dependency of barrier options requires a sufficient number of steps to accurately model price evolution.
For example, the stock price simulation,

for dt=1/10,
[image: Stock price simulation with dt=1/10]

for dt=1/500,
[image: Stock price simulation with dt=1/500]

for dt=1/1000,
[image]

It can be seen that, if you use fewer number of steps, a barrier might not be triggered which would otherwise have been triggered if more number of steps were used.
That is, increasing number of steps better models the underlying's price movement, thus increasing accuracy of the simulation. This becomes very important while pricing path dependent derivatives.

Comment: It joins the previous answer given by @Raskolnikov, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can also read through the answer to this related question:
[How are Brownian Bridges used in derivatives pricing in practice?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/36943/how-are-brownian-bridges-used-in-derivatives-pricing-in-practice/36945#36945)

Please also note that the timings mentioned are terribly slow. I know speed is not Python's strong point, but still. 3m50s for 20000 simulations with 2000 time steps (dt=1/2000) gives one the wrong idea of how efficient MC can be or not. Downloading this [pricer](https://www.acenumerics.com/option-pricer.html) you can see that this shouldn't really take more than half a second (on a budget laptop). Using this app you can also play around with the the Brownian Bridge technique and see how if you use it you then don't need such low dt's to get accurate Monte Carlo barrier prices.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I am going to read this post and its answer! I am lauching my python code through PyCharm IDE, maybe it can explain why it's pretty slow even if I'm using numpy package..? If we add that, during the execution I had other CPU-consuming programs launched, 3min50 for 40.000.000 iterations is normal?

Comment: You're welcome, let me know if something isn't clear. The fact that other programs were running may have slowed it down. What do you mean 40.000.000 iterations? As in 20.000 paths x 2000 time steps? Or something else?

Comment: Since I am performing a double loop (one for each path and the other for time steps) it performs roughly 40M iterations, am I wrong?

Comment: No that's right, that what I thought you meant. I have no idea how slow/fast Python is supposed to be for such computations. But a C++ program does those 40.000.000 iterations in 0.5 seconds. Download the program I linked to and play around if you want, price that option you priced and see what you get.

Comment: I will download and try it soon, I went on the website it seems pretty cool!
Also, I think I will run my code on Python, C++ and C# and make a kind of benchmark to see the real difference between them, think it could be interesting. Thanks @Yian Pap !

Comment: Yes, do that, I like benchmarks! Let us know what you find. Of course when two languages are not far in terms of performance (C++/C#) then the final results will depend on the specific implementation. But either way I think it's useful. In this particular example it seems like Python was hindering your work, because it was too slow for you to get converged enough results and thus be able to separate the simulation bias.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69836/discussion-between-yian-pap-and-alexm).

Comment: @YianPap I have question about this pricer. The price of continuous monitoring barrier option is really good, do you know how they price it by Monte Carlo simulations that they get so acurate results?

Comment: Hi Mister. I should know yes, since I wrote this pricer (though I don't remember much now:) The answer is using the Brownian Bridge technique, see the other post I'm linking in my answer above for more info (there's a link to an article there describing it in detail).